# pyqt app is getting frozen when trying to update the app

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt

I am trying to add self updating feature in my `pyqt` application using `pyupdater` framework when a user clicks update button it will execute

```
from client_config import ClientConfig
from pyupdater.client import Client

def check_update(self):
   APP_NAME = 'Main'
   APP_VERSION = '7.29.0'


   client = Client(ClientConfig(), refresh=True)

   update = client.update_check(APP_NAME, APP_VERSION)
   app_update = client.update_check(APP_NAME, APP_VERSION, channel='stable')



   if app_update is not None:
       downloaded = app_update.download()
       if downloaded is True:
           app_update.extract_restart()
```

Which can be found in pyupdater.org. Everything is working fine but my app is getting frozen when a new update starts downloading. how to overcome this situation?

Comment: The download is probably blocking the gui from updating. Try starting the download on a separate thread.

Comment: i tried using threading.thread() method but still not working.

Comment: What's your config file do?  It finishes for me, but that's about as exciting as it gets.